# Как разделить строку на три части и получить из неё числа?

Tags: php

Я получаю строку в виде `"1990-03-02"`.

Это, как видите, дата. Как разделить эту дату на 3 части, чтобы было:

```
$a = 1990;
$b = 3;
$c = 2;
```

Comment: `explode` или `strtotime` и  после `date`

Answer (score 3):

Раз вы работаете с датой, то можно использовать специализированные средства PHP для работы с датой/временем, а именно класс [`\DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php). А сделать это можно вот так:

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '1990-03-02');

$a = (int)$d->format('Y');
$b = (int)$d->format('j');
$c = (int)$d->format('n');
```

[Рабочий пример](http://ideone.com/IJpUha) на IDEOne.

**Замечание**:

Для данной конкретной задачи с разбиением строки на три переменные подход с использованием `\DateTime` является несколько избыточным. Однако, он дает вам с одной стороны невероятную гибкость форматирования результата, а с другой позволяет думать о дате именно как о дате, а не наборе из трех переменных. Все это, в конечном счете, позволяет повысить уровень абстракции кода и снизить его суммарную сложность.

А еще, при таком подходе вы можете запросто получать другие параметры вашей исходной даты с нулевыми трудозатратами. Вот так, например, можно получить номер недели:

```
$week = (int)$d->format('W');
```

Использование специального типа данных для даты позволяет вам делать и более крутые штуки выражаясь четким высокоуровневым языком. Например, вы можете прибавить к вашей дате [произвольный интервал](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.dateinterval.php), предположим, неделю:

```
$new_date = $d->add(new DateInterval('P1W'));
```

Comment: Покажите, как легко прибавить к этой дате неделю – пригодится многим, мне кажется.

Comment: @Sergiks, вы правы. обновил ответ

Comment: Я именно про добавление/вычитание интервала предложил, т.к. (хрустальный шар) возможно, задача ТС как раз получить что-то подобное, и он собирается прибавлять к дням 7.  А можно `$d->add(new DateInterval('P1W'));`

Comment: @Sergiks, обновил еще раз =)

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать функцию [`sscanf()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sscanf.php) для разбора форматированной строки:

```
$dateString = "1990-03-02";
list($a, $b, $c) = sscanf($dateString, "%d-%d-%d");
```

Answer (score 1):

$a = explode('-', $str); так получите разделенный массив. Ну а на ноль спереди проверить каждый элемент массива не проблема...

```
$str = "1990-03-02";
$a = explode('-', $str);
$year = $a[0];
if($a[1][0]==0){$month = $a[1][1];}else{$month = $a[1];}
if($a[2][0]==0){$day = $a[2][1];}else{$day = $a[2];}
```

либо тернарная проверка

```
$str = "1990-03-02";
$a = explode('-', $str);
$year = $a[0];
$a[1][0]==0 ? $month = $a[1][1] : $month = $a[1];
$a[2][0]==0 ? $day = $a[2][1] : $day = $a[2];
```

Comment: Зачем человеку не полный ответ?

Comment: @Дмитрий Гвоздь, ответ достаточно полный, я не счиатю что нужно отдавать сразу максимально полное решение - человек перестанет пытаться разбираться сам, тут не место для конкретных решений, помоему лучше просто подтолкнуть человека к правильному решению, но как хотите - добавил полный вариант

Comment: @Sergiks, вы правы, не предусмотрел... спасибо, сейчас поправлю

Comment: Знаете такой синтакс – `условие ? если_да : если_нет`? Например,  `$month = $a[1][0]==='0' ? $a[1][1] : $a[1];`

Comment: А так можно? Интересно, надо будет посмотреть данный вариант. Не встречал такого...

Comment: Такое выражение называется [«тернарный оператор»](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php), удобно когда одной переменной присваивается значение, в зависимости от условия.

Comment: Вообще то тенарные операторы не рекомендуеться использовать, если операца на зенд кодинг стаил.

Answer (score 0):

```
list($a, $b, $c) = explode('-', '1990-03-02');
```

Comment: Вы уверены в коде? http://www.php.su/explode

Comment: согласен с дмитрием по этому и минус отменил в експлоде разделитель укажи только

Comment: Исправил. Хотя это не самый лучший вариант. лучше используйте регулярное выражение, так можно будет проверить формат

Comment: вы действительно думаете что топикстартер тут прочитает последний ваш коммент? Он должен быть в ответе а не тут.

Comment: Зачем проверять формат? Не надо усложнять задачу ТС. А то ещё станем проверять, что месяц не 26-й, а число не 59-е : )

Comment: @IhorIvanovich А вот тип переменных у вас будет не тот. ТС хочет числа, а у вас строки. Но это я, конечно, придираюсь =)